# Automounting of USB pendrives on Debian 8 not working

Tags: debian, usb-drive

The icons appear on the desktop but I still have to mount them.
I must be missing something, mustn't I?

[image]

(The dialog is from an XFCE desktop which I used at that time, but the problem is independent of the desktop in use)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "mount them"? If the icons appear, what makes you say they're not mounted? How do you then mount them?

Comment: I still have to right click the icons and click on mount.  The kernel discovered the pin drives but they aren't automounted on /media/...

Comment: What happens if you double click them instead?

Comment: I guess this will work as well, but this is not the concept of **auto**-mounting. ;-) Why should I click around, when I stipulated (as you can see in the image) that XFCE should do it for me?

Comment: Well, it does. As soon as you double-click. There's no reason to have something mounted unless it is being accessed.

Comment: Well, well, but I want to do something with it! Not necessarily with some XFCE tool but for example with the shell or I want to access the pin drive with Emacs' dired...

Comment: That's completely different. If that's your aim, please [edit] your question and clarify. XFCE will mount it via gvfs as soon as you double click it. There may be a way to configure so that it is mounted somewhere easy to access from the shell and automatically but I don't know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26344/discussion-between-dieter-wilhelm-and-terdon).

Comment: I have Debian 8.2 Xfce desktop running, which seems to be working properly for automounting a USB flash drive. Default installed system works with those options checked, so the issue is something else.

Comment: @clearkimura: You are right, please see me answer...

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I could solve my problem.  I realised that my pin drives were mounted after all, but only for root! I guess the fault lies with the defaults of the Debian system. I found in my /etc/fstab the following entries, which I never put into:

```
/dev/sdd1       /media/usb0     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
/dev/sdd2       /media/usb1     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
```

I commented them out and my sticks are now auto-mounted as intended above! :-)